# Python problem with while loop on password check

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, passwords

I am just getting into programming recently and still many things are not clear to me. However in this code I just don't understand the logic. I premise that I don't want to use either import or def(), but I want to understand how I have to reason to make this piece of code work.

A User enters the pwd, and I want there to be a check for numbers and letters that must be present.
The first while is to avoid empty pwd; at this point I dismember the pwd and check for letters and numbers.
Enter the second while and here if I enter only numbers or only letters it works but if I put numbers and letters it keeps staying in the loop.
I tried putting a break (is commented) but it doesn't work.
If anyone can make me understand what I am doing wrong I will be grateful.
Regards

```
pwd = input("Enter password.\n")

# This loop is used to check if the User has not typed in the password.

while len(pwd) == 0: # Enter the loop when it finds the pwd box empty
    print("You left the password box empty.\n")
    pwd = input("Enter the password.\n") # Query the password

n = ''.join(filter(str.isdigit, pwd))
char = pwd.isalpha()
num = n.isdigit()
# print(char, num)

# Control loop so that there are letters and numbers 

while (char== False and num == True) or (char== True and num == False):
    n = ''.join(filter(str.isdigit, pwd))
    char= pwd.isalpha()
    num = n.isdigit()
    print("Attention the password must contain numbers and letters.")
    pwd = input("Enter password again.\n") # Prompt for password
    # break
    if (char== True and num == True):
        break
print("Password contains numbers and letters. Accepted!")
```

PS: Instead of While I tried using if, but if the User keeps putting either only numbers or only letters I have no way to go back as I can with While.

Comment: well you are trying to update n, char, and num before you enter a password (inside the while loop) therefore by the time you use your if statement to check you will be looking at the previous pwd not the newly inputted one. What you should do is move those 3 lines to after you ask the user for input

Comment: I had already tried it, I tried again just in case after your comment (thank you) but unfortunately it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

**First**, Issue you are getting is because of the line

```py
char = pwd.isalpha()
```

At this point `char` will always be `False`, unless `pwd` is only alpha. So, when you enter a password that is mix of alpha and number example `123asd`, `char` will always be `False` as you are directly using `isalpha()` method on `pwd`. What you want to do here is use same approach you used to check numbers. That mean adding the line below,

```py
c = ''.join(filter(str.isalpha, pwd))
```

before

```py
char = c.isalpha()
```

This way you are filtering all the alpha out.

**Second,** inside your 2nd `while loop`. You need to move the lines

```py
print("Attention the password must contain numbers and letters.")
pwd = input("Enter password again.\n") # Prompt for password
```

on top, before doing all those alpha and digit filters. So, that you will always have the latest value stored in the `pwd`.

**[OPTIONAL]**
**Furthermore**, using your same approach, I would suggest to refactor your code as following.

```py
pwd = input("Enter password.\n")
num = ''.join(filter(str.isdigit, pwd))
char = ''.join(filter(str.isalpha, pwd))
 
while not pwd or not num or not char:
    if not pwd:
        print("You left the password box empty.")
    else:
        print("Attention the password must contain numbers and letters.")
    pwd = input("Enter password again.\n")

    num = ''.join(filter(str.isdigit, pwd))
    char = ''.join(filter(str.isalpha, pwd))

print("Password contains numbers and letters. Accepted!")
```

Comment: Ah thank you. This code is much cleaner, I understand that too, I have a long way to go.
For char, honestly, I did the printout and it gave me True, that's why I didn't think of using the filter for that variable as well. I will keep that in mind for future codes.
For while I had no idea you could use not (very nice). 
Thanks for the explanations

Comment: Glad it was of help.

Comment: gave me the following error "NameError: name 'num' is not defined". I entered two empty varuables "num, char = "","" and solved it .

Comment: Hi @Prectux, thank you for pointing the error. I forgot to add 2 lines. If you create ```num = ''``` and ```char = ''```. Your program will not work when user enters a valid password in first attempt. So, I have edited the answer to reflect the code that works. Please look at it and sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Seen now! Thank you for your attention and code modification.